# Windows/Unbuntu - stuck at Grub menu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I have Windows 10 installed, and Ubuntu installed on a USB where I can dual boot.  Typically, when starting the computer I'd see the standard "Purple Screen"  where I can choose to boot in Windows or Ubuntu.

Recently, when I started up my computer it launched the GRU GRUB version 2.02 screen with the `grub>` prompt.  Odd, but if I typed `exit`, it'd boot straight to Windows.

In an effort to get the Purple Screen back, in Windows I followed [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@mugglestudies/common-problems-with-ubuntu-and-windows-dual-boot-installations-the-official-muggle-studies-guide-653fa37116b2) and in the command prompt typed two commands: `powercfg /h off` and then `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi`...

And now, when I do `exit` at the grub line, a message shows:

> Secure Boot Violation
> Invalid signature detected. Check Secure Boot Policy in Setup

Looking at various answers, including [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/329926/grub-starts-in-command-line-after-reboot), in the Grub menu my `grub> ls` command returns:

> (proc) (hd0) (hd0,msdos1) (hd1) (hd1,gpt[5,4,3,2,1]) (hd2) (hd2,gpt[5,4,3,2,1])

When I run `ls (hd0,msdos1)`, this returns:
`Partition hd0,msods1: No known filesystem detected - Partition start at ...`

When I do `ls (hd1,gpt2)` it returns `efi`.  But `ls (hd1,gpt2)/efi` returns `ubuntu/ Microsoft/ Boot/ dell` which is not what I'm looking for correct?

Where can I find the correct drive to `set prefix`?

Or is there something else I'm missing to just get back to Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a LiveUSB from "boot-repair" (https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files/) , it will find your OS and will redo a correct installation of your old Grub-Menu

It works in almost all cases
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: I downloaded the ISO, flashed it to a USB with Universal USB Installer (the only working PC I have now is an old Vista machine), and plugged it in to my laptop (the Ubuntu USB is still in as well).  When I boot - it still goes to the Grub screen and `boot-repair` command can't be found.  What am I not doing?  In the BIOS, Boot Option #1 is "Ubuntu", second is "Windows Boot Manager".

Comment: Ah, got it. I removed the Ubuntu USB, put in the LiveUSB - started computer, F12 for BIOS options and booted from that USB and ran the repair program.  However, when I start the computer, Grub shows up and still says "Invalid Signature Detected: Check Secure Boot Policy"  Edit: Errm, I went to BIOS, selected a separate HDD Windows thing, and Dell launched some repair thing which seemed to have also worked :)

Comment: if your Ubuntu is also on a USB drive, and you remove it... boot-repair can't see it , so cant repair the Grub :D  but with a USB boot HDD be warning to use the "UUID=" in the /etc/fstab  otherwise without this, the location and therefore the boot logic may "change", depending on the usb port used, and the order of insertion of the USBs ... UUID refers to a physical ID of the partition, not its location

Comment: You must understand that Grub uses 2 things to function, 1 / a part which is installed on one of the partitions, this part does only one thing, go look for the info of the part (2 /) the 2 / it is present on your Ubuntu partition (/ boot / grub), so if this HDD is not present or if it has changed location, well the "1 /" part is lost and do not know where to find the info ... reason of the "grub>"

Comment: if you are using a "fixed" windows on your machine, and you have the Linux on USB, it is preferable not to use Grub as a boot loader, but to leave this management to Win 10 (which knows how to boot a Linux partition from its boot menu) a boot loader will live better on a no-removable disk

Comment: if the front door of your apartment / house is moved or worse, is not always present, how are you going to get home? (through the window) Grub is the door to your OS;)